# Check for only one specific special character in string

Tags: full-text-search

I want to check if a string contains only '*' and treat replace it with blank.

For eg:
Scenario 1: if the string contains '**abc*%#' or 'xyz*$#*!' then I need to retain their values as is.
Scenario 2: if the string contains values like '****' or '*' or any combination where only this special character is present in the string then I need an output of ''.

Please suggest what would be the best way to go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? It would seem fairly simple to just iterate each character, if its not a star return the original string, then at the end return a blank string.

Comment: I am reading the data from a flat file and doinf the ETL using Talend to write data to a oracle db. So a Java function or DB level function would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting the length of the string and replacing the `*` with `''` and then subtract both of them. If the length is 0 then it contains all `*`

Example

```
int count = line.length() - line.replace(".", "").length();
```

Hope this helps.

-Help :)